# django url via proxy_pass

Tags: django, url, nginx

I would like to expose an django application in beta test to my client. Our SSL certificate work only for http://www.domain.com/ (no subdomain). So i would like to map :

http:// 192.168.0.9:8080/  to http://www.domain.com/beta/

i have add this to my nginx.conf

```
   location /beta {
            rewrite            ^([^.]*[^/])$ $1/       permanent;
   }

   location /beta / {
            proxy_set_header        X-Url-Prefix            http://www.domain.com/beta/;
            proxy_set_header        X-Real-IP               $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header        Host                    $host;
            proxy_pass              http:// 192.168.0.9:8080/;
   }
```

The first page look good, but all links doesn't works. Links are created by {% url ... %} templatetags.

PS: space between http:// and IP --> stackoverflow refuse to save my question with not reachable like

Answer (score 1):

Django needs to be aware that it is not at served at the root of the domain, default being that everything is relative to /. There are multiple ways you can handle this, but probably the easiest is to add "www.domain.com/beta" to the sites framework (you have to add it in the INSTALLED_APPS) under your default SITE_ID. Expose its models in the admin interface and set it with the proper suffix.

Look at [django sites framework](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/sites/) to add your URL root to the FQDN.